# Passing Inherited Class's Member Functor

Tags: c++, delegates, bind, functor

I'm writing a game code using C++. I want to bind the `Child`'s member function into a delegate.

I want to use `init_and_bind` function like this simplified code:

```
class Parent {
protected:
    Widget* widget;
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    void foo() {
        widget->init_and_bind(this, &Child::bar);
    }

    void bar() { /* do something */ }
};
```

I want to implement `init_and_bind` in `Widget` class, so I implemented like below code:

```
// pre-defined in engine
void Delegate::bind(Parent* object, void(Parent::* function)());

void Widget::init_and_bind(Parent* object, void(Parent::* function)()) {
    init();
    delegate->bind(object, function);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Because the `init_and_bind`'s second parameter only accepts Parent's member functor type. So I can't pass Child's member functor. So I tried to use template and `reinterpret_cast`:

```
template<typename T>
void Widget::init_and_bind(Parent* object, void(T::* function)()) {
    init();
    delegate->bind(object, function); // error
    delegate->bind(object, reinterpret_cast<void(Parent::*)()>(function); // error
}
```

But it also doesn't work. Because it is failed to cast the `Child`'s functor to `Parent`'s functor.

So, what type should be `init_and_bind`'s second argument?

Comment: `static_cast`, not `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh it works, thank you! But I don't know why `reiniterpret_cast` is not compiled.

Comment: Different casts for different jobs. The compiler will check your are using it for the right thing. Always start with a `static_cast` by default if you need to cast at all.

Comment: Pointers to members are [strange](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040209-00/?p=40713), and a `reinterpret_cast` isn't necessarily sufficient to convert from one to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the immediate solution is to `static_cast`, I think you shouldn't turn `init_and_bind` into a template. The generated code will always be the same pretty much. The only difference is possibly in how the actual cast is performed.

So you'll be getting a fair bit of code bloat, all because of a very small difference. I suggest you encapsulate that difference instead. Add a helper type to `Widget` for that:

```
class Widget {
  struct MemFunc {
    void(Parent::* function)();
    template<class T>
    MemFunc(void(T::* func)()) :
      function(static_cast<void(Parent::*)()>(func))
    {}
  };

  void init_and_bind(Parent* object, MemFunc mf) {
    init();
    delegate->bind(object, mf.function);
  }
};
```

That way, only the very small piece of code that needs templating is in fact templated. What's best, it's happening transparently on the *caller side*. And it's probably not even going to cause any bloat. Because your original non-template version required the caller to `static_cast` anyway.